# What's the meaning of "come for"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english, phrasal-verbs

From Act II of Pygmalion in the Headway Advanced book:

> Don't you be so saucy! You ain't heard what I come for yet. Oh, we are proud! He ain't above giving lessons, not him: I heard him say so.

Is "come for" synonym with "come up with" or  "face"?

Comment: What ... for = why... In other words, "You ain't heard why I come yet".

Comment: It's worth noting that a Cockney would rather say something like ***Don't you be so saucy! You ain't 'eard what I come for yet. Oh, we are proud! 'E ain't above givin' lessons, not 'im: I 'eard 'im say so."**

Comment: @Borodin Observe, however, that in Act I, after just two lines of transcription even more precise than your own, Shaw parenthetically remarks *[Here, with apologies, this desperate attempt to represent her dialect without a phonetic alphabet must be abandoned as unintelligible outside London.]* Shaw was a foreigner who spoke dialect English; and one of his many points is that it is not just the phonology but also the lexicon and utimately the substance which distinguishes dialect from "standard' English.

Answer (score 0):

***what I come for*** is properly ***what I came for***, or ***the reason why I came***

Comment: I read it rather as "what I came to get", which is similar, but not the same.

Comment: @ColinFine: In this context, ***for*** just indicates purpose. That purpose may be to collect something, but we can't tell from those words.

Answer (score 0):

You ain't heard what I come for yet = You haven't heard what I've come for yet.

She dropped the "have" in "I have come".

What she has actually come for, is elocution lessons.  So in other words, she's saying, You haven't yet heard the reason I have come here.

Answer (score -1):

The meaning of the sentence  'You ain't heard what I come for yet.'  would be 'you still have not heard/understand the reason/causes for which(what) I came here'.

'Come for' is also verb phrases and the meaning of this phrases is-
1. Come for someone to a place on order to arrest. 
2. To arrive in a place, or to enter a place : arrive, enter, reach.

Sorry for less typing beacse I post this answer from mobile.